# image not rendering despite having right src

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, css-selectors

This was working fine few 6 months back, code is not changed, now suddenly it doesn't work.

i am using jQuery to append some rows with img tags in a table
image urls are correct but doesnt show up in the table

as i said this was working fine 6 months back, maybe something in browsers changed to stop this ?

***code***

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){

  var cnt = 0;

  sendRequest();

  function sendRequest(){

      $.ajax({

        url: "/get_check_ads_one/",

        async: true,

        success:

           function(data) {
             $('#rss_table tbody').empty();

             $.each(data, function(i, item) {
               cnt = cnt + 1;

               let image_link_new = item.image_link.replace('.JPG', '.jpg');
               console.log(image_link_new);
              
               try {

                  var $tr = $('<tr>').append(
                    $('<td>').text(cnt),
                    $('<td>').text(item.title),
                    $('<td>').text(item.price),
                    $('<td>').text(item.seller_name),
                    $('<td>').append(
                      $('<img>').attr("src", image_link_new)
                    ),
                    $('<td>').append(
                      $('<a>').attr("href", item.prod_link).attr("class", "newtab").text("LINK")
                    )

                ).appendTo('#rss_table');
               
              } catch (error) {
                 
               }


             });

           },

        complete: function() {
          // Schedule the next request when the current one's complete
          setInterval(sendRequest, 100000); // The interval set to 1.6 minutes
        }

    });
  };



  $(document.body).on("click", ".newtab", function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        url = $(this).attr("href");

        window.open(url);
  });



});

</script>
```

the .jpg was coming as .JPG so i thought that might be the issue but it isn't

**i uses this to make it lowercase**

```
       let image_link_new = item.image_link.replace('.JPG', '.jpg');
       console.log(image_link_new);
```

**example image src link**

```
https://i.ebayimg.com/t/sony-kdl46r470a-lcd-tv/00/s/NzY4WDEwMjQ=/z/4pYAAOSwF41fBF-o/$_82.jpg
```

**Rendered html elemnt, tr from the table**

```
<tr><td>4</td><td>Yamaha RX-V367</td><td>€&nbsp;250,00</td><td>jose toyos</td><td><img src="https://i.ebayimg.com/t/yamaha-rx-v367/00/s/NTc1WDEwMjQ=/z/bswAAOSwYY5fAKwA/$_82.jpg"></td><td><a href="https://www.2dehands.be/a/audio-tv-en-foto/versterkers-en-ontvangers/m1572118749-yamaha-rx-v367.html" class="newtab">LINK</a></td></tr>
```

but not rendering on the table, but as i said same code worked 6 months back.

**Edit 1:**

i printed the error if there is and there isn't any on the console
the error in master.js is irrelevant this code is embedded in a html page

**console output**
[image]

I guess no error is there cause element is clearly present with proper src
its just not rendering for some reason

**this is the part where i printed the error if any**

```
   try {

      var $tr = $('<tr>').append(
        $('<td>').text(cnt),
        $('<td>').text(item.title),
        $('<td>').text(item.price),
        $('<td>').text(item.seller_name),
        $('<td>').append(
          $('<img>').attr("src", image_link_new)
        ),
        $('<td>').append(
          $('<a>').attr("href", item.prod_link).attr("class", "newtab").text("LINK")
        )

    ).appendTo('#rss_table');
   
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error); // here i printed the errorm but no error is there
   }
```

i am now seriously guessing this is something browser related,
i use firefox 82 and latest chrome 87

**EDIT 2:**

**Json dump of the data its coming from my django server**

```
[{"id": 21, "title": "Sansui T-80", "price": "Faire une offre", "seller_name": "RG HICHAM", "image_link": "https://i.ebayimg.com/t/sansui-t-80/00/s/NzI4WDQwOQ==/z/rQgAAOSwtphc4wzy/$_82.JPG", "prod_link": "https://www.2ememain.be/a/tv-hi-fi-video/tuners/m1414741399-sansui-t-80.html"}, {"id": 22, "title": "Sansui", "price": "\u20ac\u00a0150,00", "seller_name": "max", "image_link": "https://i.ebayimg.com/t/sansui/00/s/MTAyNFg3Njg=/z/0LIAAOSwnV9e9zU8/$_82.JPG", "prod_link": "https://www.2ememain.be/a/tv-hi-fi-video/decks-cassettes/m1569188623-sansui.html"}, {"id": 23, "title": "amplificateur Sansui Au-4990 ann\u00e9e 1976", "price": "Faire une offre", "seller_name": "bvasco", "image_link": "https://i.ebayimg.com/t/amplificateur-sansui-au-4990-annee-1976/00/s/NTQ2WDcyOA==/z/8cYAAOSwdvBc7V5Z/$_82.JPG", "prod_link": "https://www.2ememain.be/a/tv-hi-fi-video/amplificateurs-ampli-syntoniseurs/m1417597807-amplificateur-sansui-au-4990-annee-1976.html"}, {"id": 24, "title": "Sansui equalizeur SE-5", "price": "Faire une offre", "seller_name": "musicool", "image_link": "https://i.ebayimg.com/t/sansui-equalizeur-se-5/00/s/NzI2WDU0NQ==/z/qNcAAOSwxOBdJRjS/$_82.JPG", "prod_link": "https://www.2ememain.be/a/tv-hi-fi-video/amplificateurs-ampli-syntoniseurs/m1432415187-sansui-equalizeur-se-5.html"}, {"id": 25, "title": "T\u00e9l\u00e9commande Sansui RS-S147 neuve", "price": "\u20ac\u00a020,00", "seller_name": "Bonne affaires", "image_link": "https://i.ebayimg.com/t/telecommande-sansui-rs-s147-neuve/00/s/NTMwWDEwMjQ=/z/p-cAAOSw9yldDya1/$_82.JPG", "prod_link": "https://www.2ememain.be/a/tv-hi-fi-video/telecommandes/m1426868631-telecommande-sansui-rs-s147-neuve.html"}, {"id": 26, "title": "Superbe int\u00e9gr\u00e9 SANSUI AU 9900", "price": "Sur demande", "seller_name": "goldvintage", "image_link": "https://i.ebayimg.com/t/superbe-integre-sansui-au-9900/00/s/NTg5WDEwMjQ=/z/RTQAAOSwRLxekWgz/$_82.JPG", "prod_link": "https://www.2ememain.be/a/tv-hi-fi-video/chaine-hi-fi/m1535365072-superbe-integre-sansui-au-9900.html"}, {"id": 27, "title": "Enceintes SANSUI LM-330 Vintage", "price": "R\u00e9serv\u00e9", "seller_name": "Cacophony", "image_link": "https://i.ebayimg.com/t/enceintes-sansui-lm-330-vintage/00/s/ODAxWDEwMjQ=/z/BA8AAOSwIOhex-ZK/$_82.JPG", "prod_link": "https://www.2ememain.be/a/tv-hi-fi-video/enceintes/m1554198939-enceintes-sansui-lm-330-vintage.html"}, {"id": 1, "title": "Sansui - 331-L - R\u00e9cepteur st\u00e9r\u00e9o", "price": "Voir description", "seller_name": "Catawiki", "image_link": "https://i.ebayimg.com/t/sansui-331-l-recepteur-stereo/00/s/NDI0WDY0MA==/z/zxIAAOSwWFlfBA2x/$_82.JPG", "prod_link": "https://www.2ememain.be/a/tv-hi-fi-video/radios/a66396916-sansui-331-l-recepteur-stereo.html"}, {"id": 2, "title": "Powerboard BN4400704E BN44-00704E Samsung UE50J5550SU", "price": "\u20ac\u00a050,00", "seller_name": "Replace4u", "image_link": "https://i.ebayimg.com/t/powerboard-bn4400704e-bn44-00704e-samsung-ue50j5550su/00/s/MTAyNFg1MTE=/z/i6sAAOSw4Ppe8geO/$_82.JPG", "prod_link": "https://www.2ememain.be/a/tv-hi-fi-video/tv-accessoires/a66249730-powerboard-bn4400704e-bn44-00704e-samsung-ue50j5550su.html"}, {"id": 3, "title": "Powerboard BN4400878C BN44-00878C Samsung UE49NU8009T", "price": "\u20ac\u00a050,00", "seller_name": "Replace4u", "image_link": "https://i.ebayimg.com/t/powerboard-bn4400878c-bn44-00878c-samsung-ue49nu8009t/00/s/MTAyNFg1MTE=/z/ptYAAOSwu0Fe9KIP/$_82.JPG", "prod_link": "https://www.2ememain.be/a/tv-hi-fi-video/tv-accessoires/a66275858-powerboard-bn4400878c-bn44-00878c-samsung-ue49nu8009t.html"}, {"id": 4, "title": "Sansui mp3", "price": "\u20ac\u00a055,00", "seller_name": "Dem.042", "image_link": "https://i.ebayimg.com/t/sansui-mp3/00/s/NzY4WDEwMjQ=/z/bE4AAOSwVapfA37Y/$_82.JPG", "prod_link": "https://www.2ememain.be/a/tv-hi-fi-video/radios/m1573093906-sansui-mp3.html"}, {"id": 5, "title": "TUNER SANSUI TU-S55XL", "price": "\u20ac\u00a060,00", "seller_name": "louis Georgiev", "image_link": "https://i.ebayimg.com/t/tuner-sansui-tu-s55xl/00/s/MTcwWDEwMjQ=/z/07YAAOSwyKBfAGJY/$_82.JPG", "prod_link": "https://www.2ememain.be/a/tv-hi-fi-video/tuners/m1571938757-tuner-sansui-tu-s55xl.html"}, {"id": 6, "title": "A Vendre Platine R\u00e9vis\u00e9e 80's Sansui P-50 Essais possibles", "price": "\u20ac\u00a060,00", "seller_name": "stp", "image_link": "https://i.ebayimg.com/t/a-vendre-platine-revisee-80-s-sansui-p-50-essais-possibles/00/s/NzY4WDEwMjQ=/z/6OYAAOSwIRhe~v9U/$_82.JPG", "prod_link": "https://www.2ememain.be/a/tv-hi-fi-video/tourne-disques/m1571519834-a-vendre-platine-revisee-80-s-sansui-p-50-essais-possibles.html"}, {"id": 7, "title": "technics-dual-sansui-philips-marantz-connoisseur sugden", "price": "Voir description", "seller_name": "maurice degeneffe", "image_link": "https://i.ebayimg.com/t/technics-dual-sansui-philips-marantz-connoisseur-sugden/00/s/MTAyNFg3Njg=/z/o78AAOSw9Ide-9Wl/$_82.JPG", "prod_link": "https://www.2ememain.be/a/tv-hi-fi-video/tourne-disques/m1570672496-technics-dual-sansui-philips-marantz-connoisseur-sugden.html"}, {"id": 8, "title": "Ampli Sansui Qr 6500", "price": "\u20ac\u00a0650,00", "seller_name": "FreeHope", "image_link": "https://i.ebayimg.com/t/ampli-sansui-qr-6500/00/s/NTkwWDEwMjQ=/z/VPwAAOSw9~Be-MaD/$_82.JPG", "prod_link": "https://www.2ememain.be/a/tv-hi-fi-video/amplificateurs-ampli-syntoniseurs/m1570635463-ampli-sansui-qr-6500.html"}, {"id": 9, "title": "Sansui 800", "price": "\u20ac\u00a0150,00", "seller_name": "damsky", "image_link": "https://i.ebayimg.com/t/sansui-800/00/s/NzY4WDEwMjQ=/z/NdkAAOSwqK9e-0bd/$_82.JPG", "prod_link": "https://www.2ememain.be/a/tv-hi-fi-video/amplificateurs-ampli-syntoniseurs/m1570491497-sansui-800.html"}, {"id": 10, "title": "Sansui AU-117 , AU-217 , AU-317 poign\u00e9es rack ampli , tuner", "price": "Faire une offre", "seller_name": "Aliasse", "image_link": "https://i.ebayimg.com/t/sansui-au-117-au-217-au-317-poignees-rack-ampli-tuner/00/s/MTAyNFg3Njg=/z/sygAAOSwb~Ve-NO6/$_82.JPG", "prod_link": "https://www.2ememain.be/a/tv-hi-fi-video/amplificateurs-ampli-syntoniseurs/m1569792102-sansui-au-117-au-217-au-317-poignees-rack-ampli-tuner.html"}, {"id": 11, "title": "Ensemble sansui", "price": "\u20ac\u00a0140,00", "seller_name": "Gilles", "image_link": "https://i.ebayimg.com/t/ensemble-sansui/00/s/NzY4WDEwMjQ=/z/8pcAAOSwMTZe95bX/$_82.JPG", "prod_link": "https://www.2ememain.be/a/tv-hi-fi-video/chaine-hi-fi/m1569372849-ensemble-sansui.html"}, {"id": 12, "title": "amplis sansui 9500 avec haut parleur SP3500", "price": "\u20ac\u00a01.800,00", "seller_name": "Miele gino", "image_link": "https://i.ebayimg.com/t/amplis-sansui-9500-avec-haut-parleur-sp3500/00/s/MTAyNFg3Njg=/z/CG4AAOSw7i5e82xU/$_82.JPG", "prod_link": "https://www.2ememain.be/a/tv-hi-fi-video/amplificateurs-ampli-syntoniseurs/m1568262081-amplis-sansui-9500-avec-haut-parleur-sp3500.html"}, {"id": 13, "title": "Sansui AU-555 A", "price": "Faire une offre", "seller_name": "RG HICHAM", "image_link": "https://i.ebayimg.com/t/sansui-au-555-a/00/s/NTc2WDEwMjQ=/z/wCEAAOSwlRZe8IGh/$_82.JPG", "prod_link": "https://www.2ememain.be/a/tv-hi-fi-video/chaine-hi-fi/m1567453722-sansui-au-555-a.html"}, {"id": 14, "title": "Superbe ensemble audio SANSUI AU 6600 - TU 5500", "price": "Sur demande", "seller_name": "goldvintage", "image_link": "https://i.ebayimg.com/t/superbe-ensemble-audio-sansui-au-6600-tu-5500/00/s/Nzg3WDEwMjQ=/z/ZP4AAOSw5W9e8FaN/$_82.JPG", "prod_link": "https://www.2ememain.be/a/tv-hi-fi-video/chaine-hi-fi/m1567386021-superbe-ensemble-audio-sansui-au-6600-tu-5500.html"}, {"id": 15, "title": "R\u00e9cepteur Vintage Sansui 771", "price": "\u20ac\u00a0150,00", "seller_name": "Paul", "image_link": "https://i.ebayimg.com/t/recepteur-vintage-sansui-771/00/s/NzY4WDEwMjQ=/z/42MAAOSwCqJe7dQI/$_82.JPG", "prod_link": "https://www.2ememain.be/a/tv-hi-fi-video/amplificateurs-ampli-syntoniseurs/m1566668968-recepteur-vintage-sansui-771.html"}, {"id": 16, "title": "Revox, JBL ,Sansui,...", "price": "\u00c0 d\u00e9battre", "seller_name": "Vander", "image_link": "https://i.ebayimg.com/t/revox-jbl-sansui/00/s/NzY4WDEwMjQ=/z/XkMAAOSw-m1e56D6/$_82.JPG", "prod_link": "https://www.2ememain.be/a/tv-hi-fi-video/chaine-hi-fi/m1564799415-revox-jbl-sansui.html"}, {"id": 17, "title": "Sansui INTEGRATED AMPLIFIER A-40", "price": "Faire une offre", "seller_name": "Fred", "image_link": "https://i.ebayimg.com/t/sansui-integrated-amplifier-a-40/00/s/NzY4WDEwMjQ=/z/-swAAOSwGnJe3707/$_82.JPG", "prod_link": "https://www.2ememain.be/a/tv-hi-fi-video/amplificateurs-ampli-syntoniseurs/m1562344724-sansui-integrated-amplifier-a-40.html"}, {"id": 18, "title": "Tuner Sansui TU-7500. De 1974-75. R\u00e9vis\u00e9 par Professionnel", "price": "\u20ac\u00a0250,00", "seller_name": "Cacophony", "image_link": "https://i.ebayimg.com/t/tuner-sansui-tu-7500-de-1974-75-revise-par-professionnel/00/s/NTc2WDEwMjQ=/z/hssAAOSwP79ez2hb/$_82.JPG", "prod_link": "https://www.2ememain.be/a/tv-hi-fi-video/radios/m1556810768-tuner-sansui-tu-7500-de-1974-75-revise-par-professionnel.html"}, {"id": 19, "title": "Sansui AU-6500", "price": "Faire une offre", "seller_name": "musicool", "image_link": "https://i.ebayimg.com/t/sansui-au-6500/00/s/MTAyNFg3Njg=/z/HmsAAOSw5r5ey-Bu/$_82.JPG", "prod_link": "https://www.2ememain.be/a/tv-hi-fi-video/chaine-hi-fi/m1555752660-sansui-au-6500.html"}, {"id": 20, "title": "Sansui 350A", "price": "Faire une offre", "seller_name": "musicool", "image_link": "https://i.ebayimg.com/t/sansui-350a/00/s/MTAyNFg3Njg=/z/ZNMAAOSwm7BexpUA/$_82.JPG", "prod_link": "https://www.2ememain.be/a/tv-hi-fi-video/tourne-disques/m1553779580-sansui-350a.html"}]
```

**and i think i found why it isn't rendering, firefox is blocking it for some reason**
[image]

Any ideas ?

Comment: hi, is there an error? perhaps set a breakpoint in dev tools to see if the code is being run.

Comment: hello thanks for commenting, i added the answer in edit, this is a very simple local site, just fetching and appending the url, as i said this worked 6 months ago

Comment: Could you please remove unnecessary images from the question and just post html, javascript and error message, so it's easy to understand and reproduce? If possible, consider creating a small snippet with sample data to reproduce the issue.

Comment: hey there @Pirate thanks for commenting, i took your suggestion and removed the unnecessary images and added html code in that place.

Comment: added edit 2, maybe that's the cause, can't figure out why though

Comment: @ShantanuShady thanks for making the question more clear and straightforward. Now when you get "the resource at URL was blocked ...", what's inside if you expand that? Is it the same issue in other browsers or just one particular?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some digging, i found out the issue
it was due to default tracking protection of firefox

any type of tracking protection seems to block this domain by default

```
https://i.ebayimg.com
```

and then i thought why does it happen to chrome though ?
turns out i used PrivacyBadger extension on chrome that did it for chrome, which firefox was doing by default without any extension.

I guess this is a good thing, this became a problem because i never expected the image not showing issue to generate from tracing protection

just clicking on the shield icon beside firefox address bar and turning off tracking protection for that particular site loads the images, and for chrome, disabling PrivacyBadger and clearing the cache loads images.

thanks [Pirate](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9340890/pirate) for helping me debug this.

now images load just fine
[image]